# Memory usage goes wild with Doctrine bulk insert

Tags: php, symfony, memory, doctrine-orm

I’m trying to insert a large amount of data (30 000+ lines) in a MySQL database using Doctrine2 and the Symfony2 fixture bundle.

I looked at [the right way to do it](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html). I saw lots of questions about memory leaks and Doctrine, but no satisfying answer for me. It often comes the Doctrine `clear()` function.

So, I did various shapes of this:

```
while (($data = getData()) {
    $iteration++;

    $obj = new EntityObject();
    $obj->setName('henry');
    // Fill object...

    $manager->persist($obj);

    if ($iteration % 500 == 0) {
        $manager->flush();
        $manager->clear();

        // Also tried some sort of:
        // $manager->clear($obj);   
        // $manager->detach($obj);
        // gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
```

PHP memory still goes wild, right after the `flush()` (I’m sure of that). In fact, every time the entities are flushed, memory goes up for a certain amount depending on batch size and the entities, until it reaches the deadly *Allowed Memory size exhausted* error. With a very very tiny entity, it works but memory consumption increase too much: several MB whereas it should be KB.

`clear()`, `detach()` or calling GC doesn’t seem to have an effect at all. It only clears some KB.

Is my approach flawed? Did I miss something, somewhere? Is it a bug?

**More info**:

- Without `flush()` memory barely moves;
- Lowering the batch do not change the outcome;
- Data comes from a CSV that need to be sanitized;

**EDIT (partial solution)**:

@qooplmao brought a solution that significantly decrease memory consumption, disable doctrine sql logger: `$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);`

However, it is still abnormally high and increasing.

Comment: Did you try to lower the batch size (500)? It will be slower but less memory intensive

Comment: Yes. I try to lower it (100, 20, 1) and increase it (1000, 2000, 5000), no change.

Comment: Just curious here, what does getData() return? Where is it getting information? How much? It's interesting the choice of loop compared to the docs, I dig it

Comment: With a very low batch size, memory should not be a problem unless your entity is incredibly complicated.

Comment: Actually, I get raw data from a CSV file, I sanitize the data within the loop, and then is the part mention in the post. It loops about 8000 time and I keep track of the memory usage of each loops, it’s about 15MB, and right after the `flush()` and `clear()` it’s 35MB (for a batch of 500).

Comment: And if you do not flush you do not get the "memory exhausted" problem?

Comment: @Carlos Granados, No, my entity is quite simple, something like 10 fields and a bunch of relations. I also tried a very tiny entity (on field, no relation) and memory goes up abnormally (19MB to 25MB for about 1000 inserts).

Comment: No, I tested it again, and without `flush()`, memory is pretty stable.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Are you doing this in dev? If so, you would do well to disable the SQL logger ( `$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null)` ).

Comment: Axalix, v5.6.14, last debian version. @qooplmao, I just tried it, and it did well. It does not totally solve the problem, because it still goes up way too much, but I can say this divide the consumption by about 2 (every 200 batch flush | before: +12MB, now: +5MB).

Comment: @Gui-Don, can you try this? https://coderwall.com/p/awzjhw/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-symfony2-doctrine-entitymanager

Comment: @Axalix, that did the trick! I disabled the Doctrine profiler and logger (why does logger consume RAM?), put entities into an temporary array for the current batch then `unset` and `detach` those entities after `flush()`. Can you add a proper answer with thoses elements so I can validate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I resolved my problem using [this resource](https://coderwall.com/p/awzjhw/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-symfony2-doctrine-entitymanager), as @Axalix suggested.

This is how I modified the code:

```
// IMPORTANT - Disable the Doctrine SQL Logger
$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

// SUGGESION - make getData as a generator (using yield) to to save more memory.
while ($data = getData()) {
  $iteration++;

  $obj = new EntityObject();
  $obj->setName('henry');
  // Fill object...

  $manager->persist($obj);

  // IMPORTANT - Temporary store entities (of course, must be defined first outside of the loop)
  $tempObjets[] = $obj;

  if ($iteration % 500 == 0) {
    $manager->flush();

    // IMPORTANT - clean entities
    foreach($tempObjets as $tempObject) {
      $manager->detach($tempObject);
    }

    $tempObjets = null;
    gc_enable();
    gc_collect_cycles();
  }
}

// Do not forget the last flush
$manager->flush();
```

And, last but not least, as I use this script with Symfony data fixtures, **adding the `--no-debug` parameter in the command is also very important**. Then memory consumption is stable.

Comment: a comment on the assignment to $tempObjects. When you save the batch you detach the objects from the entityManager but you don't clear $tempObjects. This means that if you where saving 2000 items you would detach 500 objects, then 1000 objects, then 1500 objects. Does it not make sense to clear $tempObjects when the batch is saved.

Comment: @JeremyQuinton you are right, he needs to reset $tempObjects after detaching them.

Comment: If we want to insert 50000 object, but just 48000 has been inserted after executing this code, How we can identify the not inserted objects and how we can get the exact number of inserted object?

Comment: Confirmed this solution. Brought an import that was taking hours down to a few minutes.

Comment: alone the --no-debug did it for me!

Comment: `$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);` is the case... even on `env=PROD` he is still doing tons of logs...

Comment: if you ar in `dev` mode, logging is enabled by default in symfony, so one must call `$manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null)`; but if you are in `prod` this is not necessary as by default logging is disabled in prod; one can try `dump($manager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->getSQLLogger())`

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Doctrine logs all SQLs during execute. I recommend to disable it with code below, it can really save memory:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entity_manager)
{
    $em_connection = $entity_manager->getConnection();
    $em_connection->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to drop the Doctrine approach for bulk inserts. I really like Doctrine but I just hate this kind of stuff on bulk inserts.

MySQL has a great thing called [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). I would rather use it or even if I have to sanitize my csv first and do the LOAD after.

If you need to change the values, I would read csv to array `$csvData = array_map("str_getcsv", file($csv));`. Change whatever you need on the array and save it to the line. After that, use the new .csv to LOAD with MySQL.

To support my claims on why I wouldn't use Doctrine for this [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/08/07/doctrine2-batch-processing.html) described on the top.

Comment: Hm... That’s a pity, because for what I understand, some people said it is not the best tool for bulk INSERTs, mainly for a performance point of view. Yet, in my case, I don’t really care about performance (it’s some thousands of rows, not millions!). It should work normally. This being said, thanks for the help, I will try that. But, how do I conveniently make relations with LOAD DATA? Do I have to make a single CSV per table with already made relations?

Comment: Yep, I understand that performance could be something not very important to you, but if you can do it with best performance than  think it would be cool to do it. You can't do it to multiple tables, but you can create a temptable, LOAD INTO temptable, and then INSERT INTO table SELECT FROM temptable. It sounds tricky but its actually better to do it this way.

Comment: Instead of dropping down to mysql loadddata, you can use the doctrine dbal connection object (or even the pdo connection object) to prepare and execute sql insert statements.  That will allow you to insert the relations as well.  I use this approach for processing 5K or so of rather complex entities.  30K might still be a stretch.  php itself is just not really designed for large batch jobs.